# How do redis increment commands react to overflow?

Tags: redis, hiredis

In redis integer increment commands, more specifically:

```
INCR / INCRBY
HINCRBY
```

what is the behavior when incrementing 1-past the maximum value (ie 64bit signed range)?

Comment: Why don't you just try it? `SET <KEY> <MAX_VALUE>` and then `INCR <KEY>`.

Comment: @sazzad I wanted to know if this an "established" behavior or something that varies among versions. But your point is valid. I don't know if redis provides a `MAX_VALUE` but using python's `sys.maxsize` variable (which is 64 bits like in redis) I can confirm the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would error saying that the increment would overflow:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set foo 9223372036854775807
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> incr foo
(error) ERR increment or decrement would overflow
```